# Why is my .NET regex not working correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a text file which is in the format:

```
key1:val1,
key2:val2,
key3:val3
```

and I am trying to parse the key/value pairs out with a regex. Here is the regex code I am using with the same example:

```
string input = @"key1:val1,
key2:val2,
key3:val3";

var r = new Regex(@"^(?<name>\w+):(?<value>\w+),?$", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

foreach (Match m in r.Matches(input))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["name"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["value"].Value);
}
```

When I loop through `r.Matches`, sometimes certain key/value pairs don't appear, and it seems to be the ones with the comma at the end of the line - but I should be taking that into account with the `,?`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why are you using a Regex?  String.Split would be a much easier way, IMO.

Comment: 1. Regex is probably overkill for this, and 2.) your newlines are probably `CR+LF`

Comment: Love this quote: `Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.`  Obviously there is a time and a place for regex, but it's not always your best option.

Comment: I can't use `String.Split`. The actual file format is more complicated... but I can't figure out why this simplified example is not capturing the lines with the commas like I would expect.

Comment: Have you tried paolo's suggestion of allowing for whitespace after the `,`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your regular expression is not matching the newline in the first two lines.

Try changing it to

```
@"^(?<name>\w+):(?<value>\w+),?(\n|\r|\r\n)?$"
```

and it should work.
By the way, I love regular expressions, but given the problem you are trying to solve, go for the string.Split solution. It will be much easier to read...

*EDIT*: after reading your comment, where you say that this is a simplified version of your problem, then maybe you could simplify the expression by adding some "tolerance" for spaces / newline at the end of the match with

```
@"^(?<name>\w+):(?<value>\w+),?\s*$"
```

Also, when you play with regular expressions, test them with a tool like [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm), it saves a lot of time.

Comment: Your first suggestion works great. I didn't know you had to account for the actual newline itself - I thought the `RegexOptions.Multiline` handled that for me with the `$`. I made a slight change to `\r?\n?` but same idea.

Answer (score 5):

this might be a good situation for [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) rather than a regex:

```
foreach(string pair in input.Split(new Char [] {','}))
{
   string [] items = pair.Split(new Char [] {':'});
   Console.WriteLine(items[0]);
   Console.WriteLine(items[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the **RegexOptions.Multiline** option.

Comment: I can't do this, there are several hundred thousand lines in the file and some of them don't always follow the specific format I've put in my post... but I have the guarantee that each line will represent a new entity.

Comment: Can the comma appear in the **name** or **value** part of a line? If yes, then you need to change the regex to match the _last_ comma in the line.